# How do I open a browser only once inside a for loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

The code is:

```
import requests
from time import sleep
import webbrowser
from termcolor import colored


print(colored('Lowest Priced Limited\n---------------------\n', 'green'))

while True:
   lowestprice = 1234567890
   for limited in requests.get('https://search.roblox.com/catalog/json?Category=2&Subcategory=2&SortType=4&Direction=2').json():
       price = int(limited['BestPrice'])
       if price < lowestprice:
           limitedname = limited['Name']
           limitedurl = limited['AbsoluteUrl']
           lowestprice = price
   print(colored(f"{limitedname}: {lowestprice}\n{limitedurl}\n"))
   sleep(1)

   if lowestprice <= 300:
      webbrowser.open(limitedurl, new=2)
```

As you can see, the last if statement opens the URL. However, since it is inside a for loop, it keeps reopening over and over again. How do I make it open only once, while keeping **the rest of the code still going**? Not breaking the whole code and opening the URL, but opening the URL once, and keeping the code going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
import requests
from time import sleep
import webbrowser
from termcolor import colored


print(colored('Lowest Priced Limited\n---------------------\n', 'green'))
count=0
while True:
   lowestprice = 1234567890
   for limited in requests.get('https://search.roblox.com/catalog/json?Category=2&Subcategory=2&SortType=4&Direction=2').json():
       price = int(limited['BestPrice'])
       if price < lowestprice:
           limitedname = limited['Name']
           limitedurl = limited['AbsoluteUrl']
           lowestprice = price
   print(colored(f"{limitedname}: {lowestprice}\n{limitedurl}\n"))
   sleep(1)

   if (lowestprice <= 300 and count==0):
      webbrowser.open(limitedurl, new=2)
      count+=1
```

To open the WebBrowser for the Lowest Price, Try:

```
import requests
from time import sleep
import webbrowser
from termcolor import colored


print(colored('Lowest Priced Limited\n---------------------\n', 'green'))
count=0
lpep=0
lpepurl=''
while True:
   lowestprice = 1234567890
   for limited in requests.get('https://search.roblox.com/catalog/json?Category=2&Subcategory=2&SortType=4&Direction=2').json():
       price = int(limited['BestPrice'])
       if price < lowestprice:
           limitedname = limited['Name']
           limitedurl = limited['AbsoluteUrl']
           lowestprice = price
   print(colored(f"{limitedname}: {lowestprice}\n{limitedurl}\n"))
   sleep(1)
   if lowestprice <= 300 and count == 0:
       lpep = lowestprice
       lpepurl = limitedurl
       webbrowser.open(lpepurl, new=2)
       count+=1
   elif lowestprice <= 300 and lowestprice < lpep:
       lpep = lowestprice
       lpepurl = limitedurl
       webbrowser.open(lpepurl, new=2)
```

Comment: This worked very well. However lets say the lowest price is 250. Then the URL opens once, and the code keeps going. But, if the lowest price changes again, the URL does not open again. Is it possible to make it open again whenever the price changes?

Comment: you wan the url to open for the lowest price possible?

Comment: Right now, the URL opens whenever the lowestprice is less than 300 right? And, the code keeps going. As the code is going, lets say the lowestprice changes to 290 or 260 or 200 whatever. The URL does NOT open again for me. I am trying to get the URL to open everytime the price changes under 300, so I can buy cheaper before anyone else does.

Comment: try now. i've added it

Comment: for what u said now, it isint possible to make it open just one time since we cnt say when the price lowers. the code now opens for prices lower than previous lowest prices

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `bool` value to decide if it has been opened once:

```
import requests
from time import sleep
import webbrowser
from termcolor import colored


print(colored('Lowest Priced Limited\n---------------------\n', 'green'))

openedBrowser = False

while True:
    ... #other code

    if lowestprice <= 300 and not openedBrowser:
        openedBrowser = True
        webbrowser.open(limitedurl, new=2)
```